# Which Windows user am I when running a DBMS scheduled job?

Tags: oracle

My DBMS scheduled job is running a executable (VB.net).  One thing the executable is doing is copying files from one drive to another.  But one of the drives isn't mapped for the Oracle job's user.  How can I find out which user this is in order to map the drive for him as well?

Comment: DBMS scheduled jobs run as whatever OS user owns the Oracle service. By default that is SYSTEM.